# Is the total space of tautological line bundle an affine variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E_n$ denote the total space of the tautological line bundle $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{CP}^n}(-1)$  over $\mathbb{CP}^n$. That is, $$E_n := \{(l,v) \in \mathbb{CP}^n \times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}: v \in l \}.$$ Then $E_n$ is a subvariety of  $\mathbb{CP}^n \times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. Precisely speaking, $E_n$ is a quasi-projective variety sitting inside $\mathbb{CP}^n \times \mathbb{CP}^{n+1}$, cut out by $$x_iy_j=x_jy_i, \quad \text{for} \ \ i,j = 0,1, \dots, n, \quad \text{and} \quad z \neq 0,$$ where $[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ and $[y_0,\dots,y_n,z]$ are homogeneous coordinates for $\mathbb{CP}^n$ and $\mathbb{CP}^{n+1}$, respectively. Is $E_n$ also an affine variety?

Comment: $E_n$ contains $\mathbb{P}^n$ as a subvariety. Any closed subvariety of an affine variety is affine.

Comment: @loch That's a nice argument! So we can never embed a projective variety into an affine variety.

Comment: $E_n$ is the blowup of $\mathbb{C}^n$ at the origin.

Comment: @Sasha Shouldn’t it be the blowup of $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ at the origin?

Comment: @YuhangChen: Sure, that was a typo.

Comment: @loch Can the total space of an arbitrary vector bundle over a projective variety be affine? I'm not sure if the zero section is always a morphism. It is a morphism in this example so we can say the total space contains the base as a closed sub variety. But I am not sure about the general case. I formulated the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3375763/is-the-total-space-of-a-vector-bundle-over-a-projective-variety-quasi-projective). Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @YuhangChen It's always a morphism / the total space of a vector bundle contains its zero section as a subvariety. You can think about this locally - take some affine open cover where your bundle trivializes, so locally you're looking at $X \times \mathbb{C}^n$, and certainly $X \times \{0\}$ is a subvariety of $X \itmes \mathbb{C}^n$!

Comment: @loch You are right. So you are implicitly using the fact that being a morphism is a local condition on the target.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was already implied in the comment by loch, but I will post it here for completeness.

The total space $E_n$ is not affine for $n>0$. The tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^n$ has a zero section $s: \mathbb{CP}^n \to E_n$ by sending a line $l \in \mathbb{CP}^n$ to $(l,0) \in \mathbb{CP}^n \times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. It's clear $s$ is a morphism (i.e., an algebraic map described by polynomials) and its image is isomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^n$. If $E_n$ is affine, then the morphism $s$ has to be a constant map, which is impossible unless $n=0$.